# cd_storage config with Oracle

Tags: content-delivery, publishing, configuration, oracle

I have successfully set up a deployer against broker db running on Oracle, but it was necessary for me to use an SID. I attempted to configure the storage to use the oracle service name with no luck. I believe it is Oracle 11g, but will have to check the environment to be sure.

My configuration is as follows (with private info removed of course):

```
<Storage Type="persistence" Id="defaultdb" dialect="ORACLESQL" Class="com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory">
    <Pool Type="jdbc" Size="5" MonitorInterval="60" IdleTimeout="120" CheckoutTimeout="120" />
    <DataSource Class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource">
        <Property Name="driverType" Value="thin"/>
        <Property Name="networkProtocol" Value="tcp"/>
        <Property Name="serverName" Value="THE_SERVER_ADDRESS"/>
        <Property Name="portNumber" Value="1521"/>
        <Property Name="databaseName" Value="SID"/>
        <Property Name="user" Value="some_user"/>
        <Property Name="password" Value="some_password"/>
    </DataSource>
</Storage>
```

Not knowing the proper placement, I made two different attempts with the service name in the serverName and the databaseName. In all attempts to use the service name I got JDBC connection exception. I don't have the exception handy at the moment, but will update the post with it very soon.

Does anyone have experience with properly configuring cd_storage against an Oracle instance using the service name and NOT the SID. I do not wish to have any configuration requiring an SID if at all possible.

Comment: What version of Tridion are you using?

Comment: I am using Tridion 2013

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Oracle's [JDBC thin driver syntax](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/JDBC#Thin_driver) like so:

```
<Storage
    Type="persistence"
    Id="database"
    dialect="ORACLESQL"                                                                 
    Class="com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory"
    Url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=
        (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=HOSTNAME)(PORT=PORT))
        (CONNECT_DATA=
            (SERVER=DEDICATED)
            (SERVICE_NAME=SERVICE_NAME)
            (FAILOVER_MODE=(TYPE=select)(METHOD=BASIC)(RETRIES=180)
            (DELAY=5))
        ))"
    Username="SCHEMA_USER_USERNAME"
    Password="SCHEMA_USER_PASSWORD"
    Driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver">
```

More options, like load balancing, are also possible.

Comment: Works. Looks similar to my `tnsnames.ora` connection string.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried serviceName instead of databaseName?
SDL Tridion online manual has an instruction for the property when using service name in Oracle.
That instruction can be found in "[Configuring content storage](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-D7B8D088-0AD3-4652-9A61-BC86B25D04CE)" section (login required).

Comment: I appreciate your input. I don't think I stated it very clearly in the original question, but I did try the service name in place of the database name as suggested and also seen in the doc link you posted.

I received the following exception from trying this:
`Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor`